CORS issue: 500 Internal Server Error for first couple minutes
I have an issue with my application. Most of the time when I opened an app it failed to retrieve data for first couple minutes (only happens once); throwing 500 error - AxiosError .. Network Error.
Preflight returns 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
But the request fails with a 500 error no content. The console shows : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://' from origin 'https://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
And it suddenly works fine after couple minutes.
There is no log or failed request on server.
There is nothing change on the backend with CORS but I'm not sure with the network.
Edit: It seems to be Azure server issue; many people report on that

CORS is not the issue I think. The request is failing for some reason.. Kinda looks like the server doesn't accept the TCP connection at all?

CORS is a security mechanism to prevent things like Cross Site Requsst Forgery (CSRF). It only really applies to scenarios where the client connecting to the Web server is a browser, typically operated by a human user.
The browser sends an Origin HTTP header with its requests to the server. The origin relates to the domain in the URL which you are coming from. The server then validates this domain against its CORS policy, to ensure the request is coming from a trusted source, and not a malicious website which an attacker has set up to try to impersonate the victim user to carry out activities on the server.
In scenarios where the client is an application, not a human, it is very rare that the origin http header is even relevant, so CORS does not apply.
I can see you're testing this in developer tools, but you haven't included details of how the Web request to the server is being generated. If you have a local html file with a form and a button to make the request, origin will be used but will be blank, which may be causing this error.
In Postman, you'll likely see that your request does not have any origin header. This is likely why it works fine every time.
500 is a server-specific HTTP status code. If there is no failed request on the server then it's likely you need to enable failed request tracing, or other server level logging depending on what type of Web server the backend is.

Added the request in the main post. The request is exactly the same for 500 and 200.

What Web server are you using? And do you have any proxy server between you and the server, or CDN which may be caching the preflight OPTIONS request?

It seems to be Azure server issue; many people report on that
